# nuget packages folder is created in solution level and project level hint path not able to find it

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, csproj, nuget-package-restore

MVC project is unable to find the nuget package and throwing error.The missing file is packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\build\net46\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props.The packages folder is created at solution level and hint path is used in csproj as below, Any suggestions? Moving the packages folder from solution level to the project level works, but i do not want to manually do it every time as this mvc project is dynamically created and on F5 I would like the build to be succeeded.

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform">
      <HintPath>packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Change      `<HintPath>packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll</HintPath>` to    `<HintPath>$(SolutionDir)packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll</HintPath>` to make sure msbuild will search the package in Solution directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is path-related issue. Add `$(SolutionDir)` before `packages\xxx\xxx` to make sure msbuild will search the assembly from packages folder in Solution level.

It should be:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform">
      <HintPath>$(SolutionDir)packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work, after manually copy and paste the packages folder where csproj is located the build is succeeded.

Comment: Have you restored the packages before the build?  And what if change it to `..\packages\PackageName...?`  `...\Packages\` may be better. And please make sure your projects are under solution directory so that your project can access packages folder from solution level.

Comment: This seems to be not working for me. Do we have any other way using nuget.config ?

Comment: Nuget.config can specify where the packages are stored. See [repositoryPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file), it may help. And I'm really confused why my workarounds did not work, could you share the details about the error message you get.

Comment: Its working. There was an Target element in which i missed $(SolutionDir) before. Thanks.